# como fazer uma função que retorna uma lista de letras maiúsculas no python?

Tags: python, lista

olá, primeira vez usando o stack overflow, e queria saber como faço pra fazer uma função que retorna uma lista com as posições das letras maiúsculas de uma string

```
def capital_indexes(hello="HeLlO"):
    for letter in hello:
        return 

print(capital_indexes())
```

eu fiz até essa parte, mas não sei como faço pra retornar uma lista com as posições das letras maiúsculas no parâmetro `hello`

Answer (score -2):

> Dica: *das próximas vezes verifique a documentação ( [Que erro cometi ao formular minha pergunta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8388/que-erro-cometi-ao-formular-minha-pergunta?cb=1)) para formular
> a sua perunta, pois pode acabar sendo fechada por não ser formulada da
> forma correta.*

**Refente ao código:**

Você pode criar uma função que retorna uma lista com as posições das letras maiúsculas de uma string no Python usando a seguinte sintaxe:

```
def posicoes_maiusculas(string):
    posicoes = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].isupper():
            posicoes.append(i)
    return posicoes

frase = "Exemplo de Uma Frase"
print(posicoes_maiusculas(frase))
```

A função "posicoes_maiusculas" recebe como argumento uma string e cria uma lista vazia chamada "posicoes". Em seguida, usa um loop "for" para percorrer cada caractere da string. Dentro do loop, a função usa o método "[isupper()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#bytearray.isupper)" para verificar se o caractere é uma letra maiúscula. Se for, a função adiciona a posição desse caractere na lista "posicoes" usando o método "[append()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/array.html?highlight=append#array.array.append)".  Finalmente, a função retorna a lista "posicoes".

Ao chamar a função com uma string de exemplo e imprimir o resultado, você verá a lista com as posições das letras maiúsculas na string passada como argumento.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar (List Comprehension), fazendo um codigo bem mais simples com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
def posicoes_maiusculas(string):
    posicoes = [i for i in range(len(string)) if string[i].isupper()]
    return posicoes

frase = "Exemplo de Uma Frase"
print(posicoes_maiusculas(frase))
```

O único do problema desse codigo é que ele possui um assunto mais compelxo dentro na questão Python, se você é iniciante acho melhor usar o codigo com mais sintaxe, mas esse codigo é mais "Limpo".